# Why i can't split text lines received from Android in a VB6 TextBox

Tags: split, vb6, multiline

i have data in my text box named Receivedata. this textbox is received data from my android and the format from my android is:

Number_list.BarcodeValue.QuatyValue (/n)

when i received that data, The results in the textbox are in accordance with the format sent from android. so i want to input them into listview by splitting them by line and character "."
but the result is i can't split line. i set receivedata textbox multiline "true". It looks like the data on line 1 and line 2 are merged.

[image]

this is my code:
    Private Sub AddList_Click()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sValues() As String
Dim oItem As ListItem
Dim total As Long



sLines() = Split(receivedata.Text, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(sLines)
   If sLines(i) > vbNullString Then ' skip for empty line
      sValues() = Split(sLines(i), ".")

      Set oItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , sValues(0))
      Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(1))
      Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(2))

   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

so i copyed the data from receivedata to notepad and that data is merged.

[image]

why that data is merged, When viewed in the text box, their data is on a different line?

Receivedata is input from mscomm1.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    If (MSComm1.InBufferCount > 0) Then
        receivedata.Text = MSComm1.Input
    End If
End Sub
```

that data is come from my android.
i use app inventor to my android program. and that list data is in Label3 like this block.

[image]

so, when i send that list data from hp to vb, i just send the label to vb.

Comment: please specify *how* do you copied the received data to notepad

Comment: @deblocker i just copy paste like we Copied text

Comment: @deblocker i just add character ";" in the end of line. and its worked, but showed an error subscriptout of range in syntax , Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(1))  . what happen?

Comment: there is a just a silly issue with line ending characters, please add to your post how do you insert the received data to the multiline textbox.

Comment: @deblocker done, edited.

Comment: `Number_list.BarcodeValue.QuatyValue (/n)` shall be the line ending character escaped with slash or backslash in app inventor? See updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149211/discussion-between-deblocker-and-diasti-putri).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux, the same for Android, which is based on the Linux kernel. DOS/Windows uses two characters - carriage return and line feed (ASCII 13 + ASCII 10 or *\r\n*) as a line ending, whether Unix uses just one character - line feed (ASCII 10 or *\n*).

In VB6, you can use as shorthand for your convenience the built-in constants `vbCrLf`, `vbCr` and `vbLf`.

So, you have in your received data line endings, but Windows Notepad isn't able to display lines breaks by using just ASCII 10, i.e. *\n*.

BTW, there shall be somewhere another silly issue in your code, as you posted the `Split(receivedata.Text, vbCrLf)` which uses two line endings characters. feel free to refine the question with some more code, if you need the issue solved completely.

Refine the: *Number_list.BarcodeValue.QuatyValue (/n)* as follows: *Number_list.BarcodeValue.QuatyValue (\n)*.

In your receiving event change the input string as follows:

```
receivedata.Text = Replace(MSComm1.Input,vbLf,vbCrLf)
```